# Consume .NET WCF Service (Azure Cloud Service) with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, mono

Is it possible to build a standard .NET WCF Service and consume it via Mono?

Specifically Mono on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is partially supported by mono. See details: http://www.mono-project.com/WCF

Personally I have good experience with using  REST API + Mono on the Raspberry Pi and I would recommend you going that way.

Comment: Wonderful, that is exactly what I intended to consume was a REST WCF Service I currently have hosted on Azure. Thanks!